# Setup owncloud server and rocket.chat server on a single machine/ip behind a router

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, reverse-proxy, owncloud, ubuntu-18.04

I have the following scenario:

I have a static IP address from my internet provider. I have made use of that for years now on a small raspbian server on a raspberry PI running owncloud.

Now I bought a much more powerful zotac box (quad core processor, 8 GB RAM, 256 GB SSD) and I'm trying to get both an owncloud server running on https, as well as a rocket.chat server (similar to Slack) which of course should also run on https.

The Zotac box runs Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS, and sits behind an Airport Extreme router. I have 2 different subdomains on my main domain pointing at my IP address.

I have configured routing for ports `80`, `443`, and `8443` to all get directed to my zotac box' local IP address `192.168.1.33`. Example:

[image]

The owncloud server (Apache 2 with PHP 7.2 and MySQL 5.7) works on `https://cloud.mydomain.example` and I now want to make rocket.chat work on `https://chat.mydomain.example:8443`, or even better, simply on `https://chat.mydomain.com`.

Rocket.chat comes in a snap install where rocket.chat runs on a caddy webserver on `localhost:3000`. I tried to follow the https setup described on https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/ubuntu/snaps/autossl/ but wasn't able to get it to work. I also tried to set up the Apache that runs the owncloud server to work as a reverse proxy as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port, but didn't manage to get it work.

Then I tried to setup a virtual host for port 8443 with this rocketchat.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/private/ssl/apache-selfsigned.key
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName localhost
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / https://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I also don't understand why I cannot simply make my caddy listen on port 8443 (and still use https) while the Apache listens on 80 and 443.

Which would be the optimal setup for my scenario? What would be the required steps to take?

Answer (score 2):

I think the [official Rocket.Chat documentation](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/configuring-ssl-reverse-proxy/) is clear enough:

> Running behind an Apache SSL Reverse Proxy

Run this as root:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install apache2
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod ssl
a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
a2enmod rewrite
```

Add your private key to `/etc/ssl/private/chat.domain.com.key`

Lock down permissions: `chmod 400 /etc/ssl/private/chat.domain.com.key`

Add your certificate to `/etc/ssl/certs/chat.domain.com.crt`

Add your intermediate to `/etc/ssl/certs/intermediate.ca.pem`

Edit `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/rocketchat.conf` and be sure to use your actual hostname in lieu of the sample hostname “your_hostname.com” below.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin it@domain.com
ServerName chat.domain.com
ErrorLog /var/log/chat.domain.com_error.log
TransferLog /var/log/chat.domain.com_access.log
LogLevel info
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/chat.domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/chat.domain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/intermediate.ca.pem

<Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Location>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache: `service apache2 restart`

When it says

> be sure to use your actual hostname
>   in lieu of the sample hostname “your_hostname.com”

it probably means

> be sure to use your actual external https address
>   (e.g., `https://www.example.com`)
>   in lieu of `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: As I stated, port 443 is already in use on the Apache for owncloud. That's why I didn't even start to configure Apache2 as a reverse proxy with that lengthy explanantion. I need a differentiation based on the actual server name, not on port. That's why I was aiming to use port 8443. Or can you have two different virtual host files both starting with `<VirtualHost :*443>`?

Comment: Yes ! You can use *:443 for multiple vhost. Make sure to use different ServerName.

Comment: @connexo For port 443, the mechanism that allows you to do this is [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).